# merging from 1022 files open Too many open files error?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, bioinformatics, ulimit

I use samtools for coordinate sort a bam file. This command creates lots of files while running.
I run the following command
 `samtools sort -o sorted.bam genomic_dataset.bam`
But it gives the following result

> [bam_sort_core] merging from 1022 files... open: Too many open files

I searched for this and found out that there is a limit in the number of open files. The output of `ulimit -n` is 1024.
The dataset is about 560 gb and it takes about 15 hours of running. Thus, it need to create a great number of files in sorting.
Coming to my question, how can I manage to drop this limit?I am a remote linux server

Comment: have you tried for example `ulimit -n 4096` to increase the limit? I know the manual states *most systems do not allow this value to be set* but ... who knows, mine does

Comment: I tried but even 4096 isnot enough I need more. But when I try it with more number, it gives bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted error

Comment: Looks like regular users are limited to 8192 in my system, root seems to be able to go as high as it likes ... but check out `man limits.conf` - you should be able to raise the limit with "*your-user* hard nofile *some-big-number-here*"

Comment: Actually at first I thought it was about they set the limit for 4096. However I realized sth strange. When I connect to server via ssh, the first change using limit -n number works regardless of a limit. However, any later change using limit -n number, where the new number is greater than the current one does not work. What can be the reason?

Comment: yeah, it's odd, soft/hard limits and all that ... have you checked out `/etc/security/limits.conf` yet